# Opening .form file in GUI designer using intellij

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I was developing a java application in which i created  a new `GUI Form` and used the graphical interface to design the form but after everything was working and i quit Intellij idea 14 and then came back the GUI was gone and the form was only editable and viewed in `XML`. 
Why? How can i get back the GUI designer with drag and drop form building?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it closing the `XML` view and `idea 14` itself and reopening it all it worked.

Comment: yeah that was weird. happened to me too.  fixed by close the .form in the the xml view.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new gui form from a file template

```
In the Project tool window, right-click the package where you want to 
create the new form.
On the context menu choose New. The submenu contains items for all 
defined File Templates, including GUI forms.
Select the desired GUI form template on the context menu, and give 
it a name when prompted.
```

To create a file template from a gui form

```
Create a GUI form or open it in the GUI Designer.
On the Main menu, choose Tools | Save File as Template. 
The File Templates dialog displays the source code of the form. 
The extension of the new template is .form
Specify the template name, and click OK.
```

To create a new gui form

```
On the main menu, choose File | New, as described in the section 
Creating Files.
On the pop-up menu, choose GUI Form.
Specify the name of the new form, and select the layout manager.
Check the option Create bound class, and 
specify the bound class name.
Click OK.
```

You can get more info from the link below

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-opening-forms.html