# java form does not display

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am very new to java forms. Sorry about this easy question, I've searched too many forums but still couldn't find the issue. I have a simple java form, it **shows fine on Preview** but when I run the code, it doesn't show the form. I used another v**ersion which Extends the Jframe but this one shows an empty blank** form. Please help me, advise a good document if you know. Thanks

[image]

```
    package GUIpkg;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainForm implements ActionListener
{
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton Mathematica;
    private JTextArea textArea1;
    private JTextArea textArea2;
    private JButton SourceCode;

    public MainForm ()
    {


    }
   



import GUIpkg.MainForm;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Main
{
    static public void main (String argv[])
    {

        MainForm mf =   new MainForm();

    }
}
```

**EDITED**
I thought It could be like C#, when you add an object from ToolBox to your frame, the codes also automatically will be added to your behind code. like size, position etc. but here there is not anything in my constructor. So how to add objects without hardcoding the properties? I simply dragged the objects to my frame.

Comment: You're not adding any `ActionListener` to your `sourceCode` button...

Comment: There is no code to show any button either...

Comment: Are you using Swing or JavaFX? It looks like a mix which would not work...

Comment: Maybe take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967282/66207

Comment: @keuleJ I created a form with Swing with Intellij IDE.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri in them main() i make a new from MainForm, and all objects are placed on the form. So i thought the should be shown with the form all together

Comment: You create a MainForm, but inside the MainForm there is no reason as of why a JFrame, JButton or any other of your components would get displayed, they do not even get greated. But you are right in the assumption that using the UI editor should edit your code in a matching way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely does not look like a form that Java could render on the screen. Did you show all your code?

Independently of that, a good tutorial to look at is
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: oh really? yes that the whole code. because it is shown in preview i thought the code is fine. Could you help me to add what i need. thx

Comment: Could you take a look at my Edited , thanks

Comment: My take is you created the form using the IDE's UI editor. It created two files: the java code in MainForm.java, and some UI Editor data in MainForm.form. The preview is not based on the java code but on the other file. I cannot tell why your java code would not match, but what you showed is unusable.